# Make the AndroidStudio Kotlin Compiler warn me about a missing @CallSuper

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

How can I make the AndroidStudio Kotlin Compiler warn me about a missing @CallSuper?

I have some open functions marked as @CallSuper and I have implemented them from other places:

```
@CallSuper
override fun onResume() {
    ....
}
```

---

```
override fun onResume() {
    .... // no super call here
}
```

Now I saw that I indeed missed a super call at some place but the Kotlin Compiler never warned about it. I only get a warning when I directly open the file in AndroidStudio:

> Overriding method should call `super.onResume`

Is it possible to make the compiler warn about this, like it does for example for the deprecated annotation, or unused paramter, or shadowed names, etc.?